# How do you determine the velocity and acceleration components of the sleeve?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

Here is my soluation, but its wrong, so can someone help my what im doing wrong

[image]

[image]

The right answer is

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images of texts. Images should be used to post graphs, diagrams, etc.

Comment: Sorry it was too much to write

Answer (score 0):

It should be easier to get an answer by differentiating the position of the collar using the chain rule

$$ \vec{\rm pos} = \pmatrix{ r \cos \theta \\ r \sin \theta } $$

subject to the constraint $d = r \sin \theta$.

The velocity is

$$ \vec{\rm vel} = \pmatrix{ \dot{r} \cos \theta - r \dot{\theta} \sin \theta \\ \dot{r} \sin \theta + r \dot{\theta} \cos \theta } $$

and $$ 0 = \dot{r} \sin \theta + r \dot{\theta} \cos \theta $$

and acceleration

$$ \vec{\rm acc} = \pmatrix{ (\ddot{r}-r \dot{\theta}^2) \cos \theta -( r \ddot{\theta}+2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta}) \sin \theta \\ (\ddot{r}-r \dot{\theta}^2) \sin \theta +( r \ddot{\theta}+2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta}) \cos \theta  } $$

and $$ 0  = (\ddot{r}-r \dot{\theta}^2) \sin \theta +( r \ddot{\theta}+2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta}) \cos \theta $$

Now, just using the conditions to get the results out.

Answer (score 0):

starting with the position vector $~\vec R_{op}$

$$\vec R_{op}=\begin{bmatrix}
   x\\
   y\\
\end{bmatrix}=r\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\omega\,t) \\
   \sin(\omega\,t)\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
form here the velocity is:
$$\vec v_{op}=\begin{bmatrix}
   \dot x\\
   \dot y\\
\end{bmatrix}=\dot r\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\omega\,t) \\
   \sin(\omega\,t)\\
\end{bmatrix}+r\,\begin{bmatrix}
  -\omega\,\sin(\omega\,t) \\
   \omega\,\cos(\omega\,t)\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag 1$$
with
$$r=\frac{d}{\sin(\omega\,t)}~,\dot r=-d\,\frac{\omega\,\cos(\omega\,t)}{\sin^2(\omega\,t)}$$

you obtain
$$\begin{bmatrix}
   \dot x\\
   \dot y\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  -\frac{d\,\omega}{\sin^2(\omega\,t)} \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

the result are correct point P can move only towards the x direction.  analog you can obtain the acceleration